# Does NFS server as a PV respect the access mode in kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, nfs, persistent-volumes

In my kubernetes cluster, there are two nodes. Within this cluster, I have a PV with the following configuration.

```yaml
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
name: mypv
spec:
storageClassName: standard
capacity:
 storage: 5Gi
volumeMode: Filesystem
accessModes:
 - ReadWriteOnce
nfs:
 path: <file_path>
 server: <server_ip>
```

In this case, the access mode is RWO. However, pods from different nodes can successfully write onto the pv. But it should fail as per the access mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. When you're using an NFS server as a Persistent Volume (PV) in a Kubernetes cluster, the access modes are determined by the underlying storage system (in this case, NFS) rather than the access modes specified in the Persistent Volume itself.

The access modes you set (like ReadWriteOnce) don't work as strictly as they do with local storage. NFS, being a shared file system, allows multiple nodes to read and write, regardless of specified access modes. It doesn't enforce the access modes in the same way as local storage.

Access modes like ReadWriteMany and ReadOnlyMany are more common because NFS is inherently a shared file system. So, even if you set it as ReadWriteOnce, pods from different nodes can still write to it.

Answer (score 2):

As per **Neaj Morshad** and [**Access modes**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) Kubernetes documentation, using NFS as a PV does not respect access modes due to a limitation with Volume Access modes.**The access modes do not enforce write protection once the storage has been mounted.**

Note that with the help of NFS, it is possible for multiple pods from different nodes to simultaneously write to the same file on the NFS server. But this can lead to data corruption or unexpected behavior.

**As a workaround** : You can use a combination of NFS server-side configuration and **application-level locking** to enforce the desired access mode. For example, the NFS server can be configured to allow only a single client to hold a write lock on a file at a time. This would prevent multiple pods from writing to the same file simultaneously.

Comment: You can also refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681559) and [File locking](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/nfs/ch07_05.htm#:~:text=One%20of%20NFS's%20design%20goals,supporting%20record%20locks%20on%20files.) for further information related to NFS client side locking for a file.